# Compare die pool probabilities in AnyDice

Tags: anydice

I'd like to evaluate the win percentage when 3d6 keep the highest 2 [add them together] compares to 5d6 keep highest 2.

The function in AnyDice would hopefully be able to modified to compare any d6 pool to any other and to any # of keep highest X# of dice. Ideally it would be easy enough to read and that I could also substitute d10 to see how the probabilities compare.

Comment: What if a second character helped the first - the 3d6 in our example. And if that HELP allowed them to also keep the lowest value. Whether they were rolling 3d6, 4d6, 5d6, etc. Was wondering how to model how this might impact the odds. Right now it's a 75/25 split (more like 70/30 if breaking ties in the acting 3d6 favor0 and that's low odds. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output [highest 2 of 3d6] > [highest 2 of 5d6]
```

That will get you the basics: whether the first-mentioned roll will solidly beat the second (use `>=` if a tie wins for the first). I'm not sure whether you want to ensure that the kept dice are always the same in each pair of opposed rolls, or whether one side can keep more than the other, but either way it shouldn't be difficult to manage. For example, a loop to compare a few possibilities for the second side:

```
loop K over {2..4}{
    loop N over {(K+1)..5}{
        output [highest K of Kd6] > [highest K of Nd6] named "vs best [K] of [N] dice"
    }
}
```

This uses string interpolation to name the output usefully, and loop conditions that ensure nothing loony goes on with more kept dice than rolled or silly things like that.

Comment: You can also do `output [highest 2 of 3d6] - [highest 2 of 5d6]` to get the raw difference between the dice, or [use a helper function](http://anydice.com/program/6a11) to get -1 / 0 / +1 for lose / tie / win.